# Move multiple divs like matrix style background with one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am making sort  of matrix style background, images are going to drop down at random times.
I would like to pass the division's to one function as an argument to start the animation. I cannot work out how to accomplish this. I don't think its good practice to write  the same function for every graphic that drops down.
This is what I have-

```
    <div id="l_0" class="drop_leds">
    </div>
    <div id="l_1" class="drop_leds">
    </div>
    <div id="l_2" class="drop_leds">
    </div>
    <div id="l_3" class="drop_leds">
    </div>

$(document).ready(function(){

     function row_01(id){
        var movePixAmount = 10;
            setInterval(function(){
               $(id).animate({ marginTop: movePixAmount+"px" }, 10);
               movePixAmount = movePixAmount +10;
                if(movePixAmount === 600){
                    movePixAmount = 0;
                    };
                },
            100);//inter

             };
        row_01("#l_0")
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3):

Its been a quite long battle but i win (: If you do this with one function, there will be conflict or they will all have same speed.

But instead you can write 4 different `setInterval` `functions` with different speed and apply these `functions` multiple elements like 100 elements. Just define different `left`values to not cross over. [**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/TajwZ/46/)

**jQuery:**

```
var eleHeight = $('.drop_leds').height();
var windowH = $(window).height();
var count1 = 0;
var count2 = 0;
var counter;
var windowLimit = windowH + eleHeight;

counter = window.setInterval(function() {
    if( count1 >= 0 && count1 < windowLimit ) {
        count1 += 1;
        $('#l_0,#l_6').css({'top':count1 +'px'});
    }
    else if( count1 >= windowLimit ) { 
        count1=0; $('#l_0,#l_6').css({'top':'-'+ eleHeight +'px'});
    }
},1);

counter = window.setInterval(function() {
    if( count2 >= 0 && count2 < windowLimit ) {
        count2 += 4;
        $('#l_1,#l_4').css({'top':count2 +'px'});
    }
    else if( count2 >= windowLimit ) { 
        count2=0; $('#l_1,#l_4').css({'top':'-'+ eleHeight +'px'});
    }
},1);
```

**css:**

```
.drop_leds {position:absolute; width:10px;height:60px;background:black;top:0px; }
#l_0 { left:40px; }
#l_1 { left:70px; }
#l_2 { left:110px; }
#l_3 { left:140px; }
#l_4 { left:180px; }
#l_5 { left:210px; }
#l_6 { left:220px; }
#l_7 { left:240px; }
```

Comment: Blimey, thank you Barlas. Going to work out what you have done here.

Comment: @UllerUller I've found the solution to do this with one function (: http://jsfiddle.net/TajwZ/61/ looks like i've did a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case another human ends up looking here, I made a plugin that you can add to your website to make the animated matrix background work. https://github.com/manacu/manacuMatrixBg

Hope that helps!