# $.fn setInverval on multiple elements with different couting values

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, setinterval, infinite

I can manage to do infinite animation on multiple elements with different speed but i'm using several `setInterval` functions. My target is to do this with one function and when i try this with `$.fn` they all animate with same speed. Where did i do wrong ?

[Here is not accurate jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TajwZ/59/) and [here is targeted sample](http://jsfiddle.net/TajwZ/60/).

**jQuery:**

```
var eleHeight = $('.drop_leds').height();
var windowH = $(window).height();
var count = 0;
var counter;
var limit = windowH + eleHeight;

$.fn.goDown = function(x) {
    var _this = this;
    return counter = window.setInterval(function() {
        if( count >= 0 && count < limit ) {
            count += x;
            _this.css({'top':count +'px'});
        }
        else if( count >= limit ) { 
            count=0; _this.css({'top':'-'+ eleHeight +'px'});
        }

    },1);
};

$('#l_0,#l_6').goDown(1);
$('#l_1,#l_4').goDown(3);
$('#l_2,#l_7').goDown(4);
$('#l_3,#l_5').goDown(2);
```

**html/css:**

```
<div id="l_0" class="drop_leds"></div>
<div id="l_1" class="drop_leds"></div>
<div id="l_2" class="drop_leds"></div>
<div id="l_3" class="drop_leds"></div>
<div id="l_4" class="drop_leds"></div>
<div id="l_5" class="drop_leds"></div>
<div id="l_6" class="drop_leds"></div>
<div id="l_7" class="drop_leds"></div>

.drop_leds {position:absolute; width:10px; height:60px; background:black; top:0;}
#l_0 { left:40px; }#l_1 { left:70px; }#l_2 { left:110px; }#l_3 { left:140px; }
#l_4 { left:180px; }#l_5 { left:210px; }#l_6 { left:220px; }#l_7 { left:240px; }
```

[Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582507/move-multiple-divs-like-matrix-style-background-with-one-function/14584297#14584297)

Comment: aaah.. Make it stop.. I can't focus on your code when it is running on the side... (kidding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting `count` each time `$.fn.goDown` gets called, so all timers end up using the same `count` value. Move it to inside your plugin's inner scope to fix the issue:

```
$.fn.goDown = function(x) {
    var count = 0;
    var counter;
    var _this = this;
    return counter = window.setInterval(function() {
        if( count >= 0 && count < limit ) {
            count += x;
            _this.css({'top':count +'px'});
        }
        else if( count >= limit ) { 
            count=0; _this.css({'top':'-'+ eleHeight +'px'});
        }

    },1);
};
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TajwZ/61/)

This way, each interval `counter` will have a corresponding `count` variable only accessible inside the execution context that created the interval. Exactly as how you scoped the `_this` inside of the plugin's scope.

Comment: Thanks mate, looks like i've did a simple mistake (: